# Disable Space key for WebBrowser

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, controls, webbrowser-control

When the user focus on webBrowser Control and Press <kbd>Space</kbd> key the webBrowser Scrolls Down.
How can I disable this event?

Comment: That's by design, and expected behavior by the user. Try it in any browser on your computer. You shouldn't be trying to disable this.

Comment: I need to customize this behavior.

Comment: Apparently you missed the point. You shouldn't be customizing that behavior. You shouldn't be doing anything at all with it. The control is *designed* that way, it's *supposed* to work that way, the user will *expect* it to work that way, and if it doesn't in your application, **then your application is/will be broken**. If you find yourself needing to customize this behavior, there is something seriously wrong with your design. Post a question about that, instead. You'll get much better help.

Comment: In my situation, I need a webBrowser Control that firing my custom event on space-key pressing (**instead of** scrolling down not after it). so what is the prob !?

Comment: @Cody: There are rules... and there are always exceptions.

Comment: @Nick: And there are lots of broken applications. What's your point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this javascript code solve my problem:

```
onkeypress='if(event.keyCode=13) return false;'
```

because the false returning for spaceKey prevent the webBrowser from scrolling down!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to interrupt the keyboard event from your application and cancel the event information being sent to your control, make sure you don't cancel <kbd>Space</kbd> Key all the time as it would be required in other places.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx

Hope that helps !!

Comment: I have add an event for space key pressing. but after firing this event the webBrowser scroll down!

Comment: do you mean that you have you cancelled that event and it still doesnt work?

Comment: I add my custom code in webBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown event and after firing that event then the webBrowser automatically scrolled down.

Comment: you need to interrupt the keyboard event on the application which contains the  webBrowser1, you cannot override the default event which is built into the control itself.

Comment: I have handle the Space key pressing in custom PreviewKeyDown event but the problem still exist!

Comment: In that case the only other option which i can think of is using java script to prevent this from happening, I know its a bad way but i cant think of any other way to prevent his event from happening.

Comment: JavaScript is a **terrible** option. For one thing, you don't necessarily control the pages that the user opens in the browser. Why not take a hammer to the spacebar key instead? It makes just as much sense.

Comment: I agree Javascript is **not** a good option, as I mentioned earlier, I cant think of other ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

use the **_PreviewKeyDown** event

example:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:scroll(0,0)")

End If
```

;)